# Izpack toggel Checkbox on Install Location

Tags: java, izpack

I have a `checkbox` for Windows Service installation in a `UserInput` Panel and i would want to make this dependent with the installation path.

If the installation path is local drive, then the "install windows service" `checkbox` should appear.
But if the installation path is a Network Shared location or a mounted Drive , the checkbox shouldnt appear.

For this i tried using [Dynamic variable](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#dynamic-variables) along with a [Condition](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#the-conditions-element-conditions)

Here is the snippet from install.xml

```
<conditions>
        <condition type="variable" id="install.path.condition">
            <name>$INSTALL_PATH</name>
            <value>//</value>
        </condition>
    </conditions>

    <dynamicvariables>
        <variable name="windowsservice" value="false" condition="install.path.condition" />
        <variable name="windowsservice" value="true" condition="!install.path.condition" />
    </dynamicvariables>
```

The target field in install_userinputspec.xml

```
<field align="left" type="check" variable="windowsservice" conditionid="install.path.condition" revalidate="true">
            <os family="windows"/>
            <spec txt="Install as Windows Service" id="windowsServiceCheckbox" true="on" false="off"
            set="false" />
        </field>
```

I tried my luck getting this work, but it wont. Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `$INSTALL_PATH` to `INSTALL_PATH`

   ```
   <name>INSTALL_PATH</name>
   ```
2. If you're not sure about the *exact value* that will be entered for the `INSTALL_PATH`   then instead of using a condition of `type="variable"` use `type="contains"`with a nested `<variable>` tag, such as:

   ```
   <condition type="contains" id="...">
       <variable>INSTALL_PATH</variable>
       <value>a substring to match in the value of INSTALL_PATH</string>
   </condition>
   ```

   [IzPack doc contains cond.](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Contains+Condition)
3. Use `revalidate="yes"` as an attribute of the `<spec>` tag and not the `<field>` tag itself.
4. First, try to make your `<condition>` work. Once you've tested that, the `check` field can be linked to the condition directly for **enabling/disabling** and as such, you do not need to use `<dynamicvariables>` in this case, unless you need it for something other than checkbox-enable-disable-based-by-INSTALL_PATH.